# Adding Servers to SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2008

I would like to add a bunch of SQL (mixture of 2000-2005) server instances on different servers to my SSMS (SQL Managment Studio) Registered servers, I was following this tutorial [here](http://sev17.com/2008/12/registering-sql-servers-in-2000-em-2005-ssms-and-2008-ssms/) but this only adds one server at a time not all at the same time.

The list is currently in Excel but can be imported to notepad or any other document format as long as it can be recognized by the PowerShell command. Also, another thing to note is where can i change the login to use sql authentication? and specify username and password?

```
New-Item $(Encode-Sqlname "SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME") -itemtype registration -Value “server=MyServer;integrated security=true”
```

tks

ERROR

```
New-Object : Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "", for "PSCredential" to
 type "System.Security.SecureString": "Cannot convert the "" value of type "Sys
tem.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString"."
At line:4 char:32
+         -Credential (New-Object <<<<  System.Management.Automation.PSCredenti
al("sa", "")) }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.Power
   Shell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save the Excel spreadsheet as a CSV file, you can easily import it in PowerShell using the [Import-Csv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx) cmdlet and automatically register the servers in the list by their *names*.

Assuming your CSV file looks like this:

```
|Name    |
|Server1 |
|Server2 |
|Server3 |
```

The following command will import its content **as a list of objects**, one for each row in the CSV file, all having a `Name` property, which contains the actual value. Those names are then used *within the string* passed to the [New-Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176914.aspx) cmdlet to actually do the registration:

```
Import-Csv ServersToRegister.csv | ForEach-Object { `
    New-Item $(Encode-Sqlname $_.Name) -ItemType Registration `
        -Value ("server=$($_.Name);integrated security=true") }
```

You can specify the username and password to use to connect to the SQL Server instance by passing a [PSCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms572524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object to the [New-Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176914.aspx) cmdlet. So the complete command would be:

```
Import-Csv ServersToRegister.csv | ForEach-Object { `
    New-Item $(Encode-Sqlname $_.Name) -ItemType Registration `
        -Value ("server=$($_.Name);integrated security=true") `
        -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("username", "password")) }
```

Comment: I think u mean .csv and not cvs?

Comment: @JackyBoi Of course. I corrected my answer. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: OK i am getting the following error where it says the value cannot be converted to system.security.securestring, specific error i pasted in the original question..other than that i am guessing it is processing all the code before that ? (just a guess!) but tks man!!

Comment: ok just to double check i have tried to run the code with out the credential parameter.. and surprisingly get the following error New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'LEMSSP
ROD25\LEWSQL25'.
At line:2 char:13
+     New-Item <<<<  $(Encode-Sqlname "SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME") -ItemType Regi
stration `
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindin
   gException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell
   .Commands.NewItemCommand

Comment: The above comment was too long so anyways i c that the server is being brough over but not able to add.. is it because i am specifying as SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME in .csv file as a single column?

Comment: @JackyBoi Is `SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME` also part of the CSV file? If yes, what's the name of the column? The `Import-Csv` cmdlet will generate objects with properties named after the columns in the source CSV file. What's the output of `Import-Csv YourFile.csv`?

Comment: to answer ur first question is basically answering ur question, so yes when i say import-csv C:\MYfile.csv i get the list of all the servers exactly like you showed me in ur answer like NAME (With dotted line below) and list of all the servers..what would u like me to test next? this is fun! good analytical skills bro

Comment: and in your answer did u meant to put the " ' " single quote character at the end of each line or stackoverflow did that for u?

Comment: The ` character is the escape character in PowerShell. I used in my example to break the command into multiple lines to make it more readable. Try running the `New-Item` command alone by hard coding the name of the first server in the list: `New-Item $(Encode-Sqlname "SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME") -ItemType Registration -Value "server=FirstServerNameInTheList;integrated security=true"`

Comment: ok if one server it adds fine, how to specify all the servers that i am adding from the .csv to b added in a folder/ group?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7629/discussion-between-enrico-campidoglio-and-jackyboi)

Comment: Import-Csv C:\serverlist.csv | ForEach-Object { New-Item $(Encode-Sqlname $_.Name) -ItemType Registration -Value ("server=;$($_.Name);integrated security=true") }  this is the correct code take note

Comment: HI Enrico what about the password not being able to be converted from system.securestring to string problem?..just what to know :)

Comment: i noticed this here but not sure how to implement this  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315356.aspx