# Powershell script automation

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssms

I managed to grab the concept of for-each and the SSMS application programming and also reading from excel file thru this question

[Adding Servers to SQL Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256207/adding-servers-to-sql-management-studio)

This is the code that is working for me now

```
Import-Csv C:\sl.csv | ForEach-Object { New-Item $(Encode-Sqlname $_.Name) -ItemType Registration -Value ("server=;$($_.Name);integrated security=true") }
```

But I was having a problem with getting the user name and password to be auto-configured,
which means changing the above code to this

```
Import-Csv C:\sl.csv | ForEach-Object { New-Item $(Encode-Sqlname $_.Name) -ItemType Registration -Value ("server=;$($_.Name);integrated security=false") }
```

but that is ok that is how the people I am delivering the script to prefer, for security purposes.(even though I would like to know how to get it done :))
Now for further enhancement, there are quite a number of mirrored servers, like

server1/instance2a

server2/instance2b

so the thing is I want to know in the registered servers window
[image]

there are mirrored and the principal servers, which means when the server is registered the name I want to make it appear like this, ***server1/isntance2a (mirror)***, so when the user wants to login he easily knows which is the mirror or prinicipal server. So to determine this the sql query is this.

```
select mirroring_role_desc from sys.database_mirroring where database_id > 4 and mirroring_state is NOT NULL
```

the output of this will give me this

```
mirroring_role_desc
PRINCIPAL
PRINCIPAL
PRINCIPAL
PRINCIPAL
PRINCIPAL
```

This query will run and determine first if it is a mirrored instance, if it is then display the number of principal databases in the instance. From here I want to take the output and display the registered server name according to the specifications I mentioned above.

BUT when there is a failover the registered server name still shows as ***server1/instance2a*** even though it is the mirrored now, so as by now you can understand that I am trying to make this script dynamic so the user can run this when ever he wants or it is run every fortnight or something like that (not to worry about the schedule for now)